# Terminal Services Licensing Server Does Not Hand Out Available CALs (Error 22)

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-server

We have a TSLS (2008 SP2, not R2) issuing both 2003 and 2008 Per Device CALs. I have no Issues with the 2008 CALs. It has 5 or so batches of 2003 CALs, and hands out some (group A), but not others (group B). When CALs run out on group A, it doesn't grab CALs from Group B, and throws error 22. Of note, this for a Citrix xenapp implementation.

This is what the event log says:

```
Log Name: System 
Source: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Licensing 
Date: 
Event ID: 22 
Task Category: None 
Level: Warning 
Keywords: Classic 
User: N/A 
Computer: 
Description: 
The Terminal Services license server "TS licensing server name" does not have any 
Terminal Services client access licenses (TS CALs) installed and registered with 
the Microsoft Clearinghouse for product "Windows Server 2003 - Terminal Server Per 
Device CAL Token". Therefore, the Terminal Services license server cannot issue TS 
CALs of the type "Windows Server 2003 - Terminal Server Per Device CAL Token" to 
the terminal server "IP of a TS". To resolve this problem, install additional TS 
CALs as required.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say group a vs. b, are you reffering to different servers or different groups of CALs?

if it's the former, i would confimr that your terminal server can see both TSL servers (meaning A and B).  Forget off the top of my hand where in LDAP it is, but theres an entry (site level) that stores what TSL servers are avaialabe.

If it's the latter, i would simply call the MS clearing house and get both groups combined into a single group of CALs.